# Count value between datetime and NaT

Tags: pandas, dataframe, map-function

I have two python pandas dataframes, in simplified form they look like this:

DF1

```
+---------+---------+------+-------+
| Date_in | Date_out| Group| Item  |
+---------+---------+------+-------+
| 1991-08 | 2000-08 |   A  |   A1  |
| 1992-08 |   NaT   |   A  |   A2  |
| 1997-02 |   NaT   |   B  |   B1  |
| 1998-03 | 2001-03 |   C  |   C1  |
| 1999-02 | 2002-02 |   D  |   D1  |
| 2000-02 |   NaT   |   D  |   D2  |
| 2000-03 | 2001-04 |   D  |   D3  |
| 2001-08 |   NaT   |   D  |   D4  |
+---------+---------+------+-------+
```

DF2

```
+---------+-------+
|  Date   | Group | 
+---------+-------+
| 2000-01 |   A   | 
| 2001-02 |   A   | 
| 2001-03 |   B   |
| 2001-04 |   B   | 
| 2001-05 |   C   | 
| 2001-06 |   C   |
| 2001-03 |   D   |
| 2001-07 |   D   |
+---------|-------+
```

I want to count how many item still existed in Group column DF2 based on date constraint in DF1

Desired output

```
+---------+-------+-------+
|  Date   | Group | Total |
+---------+-------+-------+
| 2000-01 |   A   |   2   |
| 2001-02 |   A   |   1   |
| 2001-03 |   B   |   1   |
| 2001-04 |   B   |   1   |
| 2001-05 |   C   |   0   |
| 2001-06 |   C   |   0   |
| 2001-03 |   D   |   3   |
| 2001-07 |   D   |   2   |
+---------|-------+-------+
```

Comment: whats the logic to get desired output?

Comment: Yes sir @jezrael, because A1 (out at 2000-08) still exist at 2000-01

Comment: got it. just figured out. I think @jezrael is too quick. He has answered

Comment: @JoeFerndz - Nat means still exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert all datetimes and replace missing `NaT` to today date in first step:

```
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df1['Date_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_in'])
df1['Date_out'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_out']).fillna(pd.to_datetime('now').normalize())
print (df1)
     Date_in   Date_out Group Item
0 1991-08-01 2000-08-01     A   A1
1 1992-08-01 2021-02-12     A   A2
2 1997-02-01 2021-02-12     B   B1
3 1998-03-01 2001-03-01     C   C1
4 1999-02-01 2002-02-01     D   D1
5 2000-02-01 2021-02-12     D   D2
6 2000-03-01 2001-04-01     D   D3
7 2001-08-01 2021-02-12     D   D4
```

Then get all months between `Date_in` and `Date_out` and count months with groups by [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
L = [pd.Series(r.Group,pd.date_range(r.Date_in, r.Date_out, freq='MS')) 
     for r in df1.itertuples()]
s = (pd.concat(L)
         .reset_index(name='Group')
         .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='index', freq='MS'), 'Group'])
         .size()
         .rename('Total'))

# print (s)
```

And last add new column with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and replace `NaN` to `0` for not matching values:

```
df2 = df2.join(s, on=['Date','Group'])
df2['Total'] = df2['Total'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df2)
        Date Group  Total
0 2000-01-01     A      2
1 2001-02-01     A      1
2 2001-03-01     B      1
3 2001-04-01     B      1
4 2001-05-01     C      0
5 2001-06-01     C      0
6 2001-03-01     D      3
7 2001-07-01     D      2
```

EDIT:

In real data is necessary working with `days`, not datetimes, so solution is a bit modified:

```
#remove times
df2['date'] = df2['created_at'].dt.normalize()

#convert date_range by days
L = [pd.Series(r.dept_name,pd.date_range(r.start_date, r.end_date, freq='d')) 
     for r in df1.itertuples()]
s = (pd.concat(L)
    .reset_index(name='dept_name')
    .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='index', freq='D'), 'dept_name'])
    .size()
    .rename('total_member'))

#join by column date (without times)
df2 = df2.join(s, on=['date','dept_name'])
df2['total_member'] = df2['total_member'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Still wondering why I still got zero for all values in Total column?

Comment: @yogapurbaya - are correct datetimes after `df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df1['Date_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_in'])
df1['Date_out'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_out']).fillna(pd.to_datetime('now').normalize())` ?

Comment: Check it `print (df1)` and `print (df2)`

Comment: Yes, every date columns are correct dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: @yogapurbaya - yes, but if matching - it means if exist in `df2` datetimes between df1 datetimes.

Comment: Actually my both dataframes are not in the exact same shape like above instance, could it be caused by the join or the concat method?

Comment: @yogapurbaya - No, it is not necessary same shape. Only necessary if exist dates between df1 in df2. Are you sure all values in `Total` are `0` ? If use `df2[df2.Total != 0]` it return no rows?

Comment: Yes, everything in Total are 0, and even after executing this df2[df2.Total != 0] script, only return column name without any value

Comment: I could share everything out by email if you don't mind spending time solving on this petty little thing